# How can I HTML encode text that may have html tags without encoding the tags themselves in Javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, html-encode

Basically I have some text that may contain HTML tags but may also contain non-HTML encoded characters.

```
var doc = window.document.implementation.createDocument
    ('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html',  null);
var text = '<head><script>somejs</script>' +
      '<script>var x = 7; var y = 5; var foo = x < y;</script>' +
      '</head><body></body>');
```

I wish to set text to an elements innerHTML attribute.  If I just do

```
doc.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = text;
```

This causes a INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 because of the less than sign between x and y.

However, if I htmlEncode the variable text I get

```
&lt;head&gt;&lt;script&gt;somejs&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script&gt;var x = 7; var y = 5; var     foo = x &lt; y;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;/body&gt;
```

And thus I lose all the tags which I need for the element to behave as desired once its innerHTML has been set.  Is there any standard way to htmlencode the contents of all the tags in a string without encoding the tags themselves?

Comment: use `escape` and `unescape` to get your result.

Comment: Unfortunately that escapes the entire string so that if I then wanted to do something like doc.getElementsByTagName('script') I would get nothing because the < and > that compose the script tags have been escaped.

Answer (score 0):

For inline scripts [you need to escape the string `</script` when followed by a space character, `>`, or `/`, else it would close the respective opening tag](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/etago).

So, instead of `</script>`, you could use `<\/script>`. This works:

```
var text = '<head><script>somejs<\/script><script>var x = 7; var y = 5; var foo = x < y;<\/script></head><body></body>';
el.innerHTML = text;
```

**Update:** Now that you’ve edited your question, I see you’re using XHTML! That explains it — `innerHTML` doesn’t work in XHTML.

Comment: I edited my question to show my actual use case, sorry I wasn't more clear at first.  For me, in the above case I still get the INVALID_STATE_ERR even if I especape the forward slashes.  However, if I change 'x < y' to 'x + y' I do not get the error suggesting that it is the < symbol that is the problem and that it needs to be htmlencoded.

Comment: @user959986 If you want to escape the `<` character, [you can](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#0%3C), but it shouldn’t be necessary.

Comment: Ah, my bad :/ I'm a bit of a noob. I don't really care which I use.  All I want is to be able to later call var scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName('script') and then be able to get 'somejs' by doing scripts[0].innerHTML;  Any way to make this work?  Basically I just want to pull all the javascript code that is between a pair of <script> and </script> tags from the variable text.